# when a method should return a value java

Tags: java, eclipse, return

I am a new user for java and I am a little confused on whether a method should return a value or not in java for example I wrote this simple method

```
public static void increase_user() {
  int number=3;
  if(number<10)
    user++;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  int user=10;
  increase_user();
  System.out.println(user);
}
```

Should I make increase_user method return a value in this case? and when it should return a value?

Comment: If you want to update the user variable in main method then you need to return int from increate_user() method,

Comment: If you want any output of the method then you should add any return other than void

Comment: thank you guys for your answer but If I make the user variable as a static variable then should I still put the return statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.) You need to pass the `user` object.

2.) Also need to return the `user` object.

```
 public static int increase_user(int user) {
        int number = 3;
        if (number < 10)
            user++;

        return user;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int user = 10;
        user = increase_user(user);
        System.out.println(user);
    }
```

Making `User` variable `static`, works same as above, no need to pass/return user object

```
public class Test2 {
    static int user = 10;

    public static void increase_user() {
        int number = 3;
        if (number < 10)
            user++;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        increase_user();
        System.out.println(user);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but If I make the user variable as a static variable then should I still put the return statement

Comment: @jonekemberly no need then, answer updated, no need to pass or return user object

Answer (score 0):

it's a case by case answer. Return a value when you need one. e.g. `addUser()` might return a new `User` object. `setUserName()` probably doesn't have a return value.

In you case, perhaps return a boolean to indicate whether the value was increased or not?